# Infinite Scroll in AngularJs Single Page Application

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll

I'm developing a single page application and I've huge content with images and I'm representing the data on my page using lists. I'm already using ngInfiniteScroll, till some extent of the scrolling the performance of the page is perfectly fine, but after certain point it scrolling very slowly and I know it is because of the amount of data the I've loaded in to the memory previous to this point. Any suggestions on how can I improve the performance with the same scroll speed through out the page. Is there any better alternative to infinite scroll.

Comment: Not sure if this would help much, but have you tried one-way binding?  {{::obj.property}}

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ui-Grid. They are doing exactly what you need. They use Virtualization for rendering large data.

URL :  [Ui-Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) [infinite grid scroll](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/212_infinite_scroll)

other example: [ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html)

Comment: I've been using the ngInfiniteScroll, I've figured out that adding this <div style="clear:both"></div> at the end of container that grows as the items get added. But the problem that I've right now is that there is little lag in adding more items when it reaches the end of the items as you scroll. Can anyone suggest what else can I try.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material has a really nice implementation of this built in with md-virtual-repeat.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat